# Combinatorics questions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given that $n$ is an even number, $V=\{1,2,\dots ,n\}$, we are asked how many graphs $G=(V,E)$ there is such that no even numbered vertex is connected to another even vertex, i started and said that there is $\binom{n/2}{2}$ pairs of even vertexes, and for each pair there is 2 options either we connect or not, this gives $2^{n/2 c 2}$ options, i said that the total number of graphs without the condition is $2^n$ cause for each $v$ in $V=\{1,2,\dots ,n\}$ we can choose it to be in G or not to be, in total i said we have $2^n\cdot 2^{n/2 c 2}$ graphs like those. Is my approach right?

Comment: To be clear... when you say "even vertex" do you mean a vertex whose *label* is even?  Or a vertex whose *degree* is even?

Comment: it means even numbered vertexes

Comment: No, your attempt is not correct.  So, there are $\binom{n}{2}$ possible edges... $\binom{n/2}{2}$ of which are between even-numbered vertices.  That leaves $\binom{n}{2}-\binom{n/2}{2}$ edges which are either between odd-numbered vertices or between an odd-numbered and an even-numbered vertex.  Can you finish from there?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach involving inclusion/exclusion.

For $x\neq y$ let $A_{\{x,y\}}$ denote the collection of graphs that contain the edge $\{x,y\}$.

Notice if $e_1,..,e_k$ are distinct edges, then $A_{e_1}\cap\dots \cap A_{e_k}$ has size $2^{{n \choose 2}-k}$. So, from inclusion/exclusion and the binomial theorem, we have that $$\Bigg|\bigcup_{x,y\in \{2,...,n\}, x< y} A_{\{x,y\}} \Bigg|=\sum_{k=1}^{{n/2 \choose 2}}{{{n/2 \choose 2}} \choose k}(-1)^{k-1}2^{{n \choose 2}-k}=2^{{n \choose 2}}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n/2 \choose 2}}\right)$$

Since there are $2^{{n\choose 2}}$ total graphs, we have  $$2^{{n\choose 2}}-\Bigg|\bigcup_{x,y\in \{2,...,n\}, x< y} A_{\{x,y\}} \Bigg|=2^{{n \choose 2}-{n/2 \choose 2}}$$ favorable graphs, which corresponds to the suggestion made by @JMoravitz.

Answer (score 0):

I'll call graphs satisfying the desired property "good graphs" and let $G_{2k}$ be the number of good graphs with $2k$ vertices.

A good graph with $2k+2$ vertices can be obtained from a good graph with $2k$ vertices by choosing how to connect the new vertices $(2k+1)$ and $(2k+2)$ with the old vertices.

There are no restriction on vertex $(2k+1)$ so it can be connected in $2^{2k}$ ways.

Regarding the vertex $2k+2$, it can be connected to the old vertices in just $2^k$ ways (because it can't be connected with even vertices).

Last but not least you have to choose if $2k+1$ and $2k+2$ are connected or not ( $2$ choices). So

$$\begin{cases}G_{2k+2}=2^{3k+1}G_{2k}\\ G_2=2\end{cases}$$

Can you find a closed formula now?